# Explanation of what is going on with this query using "ROUND" function

Tags: rounding, sqlplus

Just need some clarification on how this round function is working so I can use it in some of my own work.

```
SELECT  "OrderId","CustomerId","OrderNumber","OrderDate",
ROUND(TO_DATE(sysdate,'dd-mm-yy')-"OrderDate",1)AS "Number Of Days",
ROUND((TO_DATE(sysdate,'dd-mm-yy')-"OrderDate")/30.4167,1)AS "Number Of Months" 
FROM "SA_Order" WHERE "Fulfilled"='Y';
```

This is the original query:

Display all the Orders that have been fulfilled and the numbers of days since the order date (round down
to one decimal place).

I'm struggling to find other examples that explain what is actually going on within the query.